# Filter not working when 5 digit price

Tags: javascript, filter, datatables, price

I am using this code to filter in asc and desc of prices...
Problem is when I filter with 5 digit value than it's not working properly

```
    $(".deskprice1").click(function () {
       var filterType = $(this).attr("data-filter"); // return data-price
       var type = $(this).attr("data-sort"); // return asc or desc
       $('.flight-list .filter').sortElements(function (a, b) {
             // one by one prices
                return type == "asc" ? ($(a).attr(filterType) > $(b).attr(filterType) ? 1 : -1) : ($(b).attr(filterType) > $(a).attr(filterType) ? 1 : -1);
       });
       type = type == "asc" ? "dasc" : "asc";
      $(this).attr("data-sort", type);
   });
```

Comment: Oh my god please dont ever nest ternary operators

Comment: sorting numbers as strings gets messy

Comment: I am using this js

Comment: https://github.com/padolsey-archive/jquery.fn/blob/master/sortElements/jquery.sortElements.js